Is there a mathematical expression linking effort required to lift a weight and the weight value?
I have no idea if this is the right forum but here we go
I'm basically wondering if there is a math expression linking the amount of effort required to lift a weight at the gym, and the value of the weight
I know there is an expression for work performed
$W=FΔd=maΔd$
However, it is linear with respect to mass. If I lift a weight of x
kg at the gym for 10 reps, and I increase the weight to 10x
kg, I am unable to do even a single rep. So the relationship I am looking for is non-linear with respect to mass.
In essence I want to be able to answer a question of the form:
"I can do 10 reps with x
weight, what is the formula to find the weight at which I can do only 5 reps?"

Please remember to take the [tour], read-up in the [help] and delete the copy of this question on biology.

You're looking for a 1RM (1 repetition maximum) calculator.
Here's an example: https://exrx.net/Calculators/OneRepMax
There's no formula, these are just interpolating averages of observed values. There is also huge inter-individual variation in actual results stemming from differences in both genotype and training. I.e. An individual may be genetically predisposed to having muscles that are either more endurant or better at brief maximal exertions. They may also have specifically trained to be better at endurance efforts or maximal strength efforts. These factors will introduce uncertainty or inaccuracy into the predictions made by models like this. The data on which these models were formed was also taken from athletes, so their results are also likely to be inaccurate for less trained individuals.
